# Creating different streams for different sounds using soundcloud spi

Tags: javascript, api, sdk, soundcloud

i have three five playbuttons on my page and each has the same class but different id's

```
<img class="song" id="0001" src="images/play-button.png">
<img class="song" id="0002" src="images/play-button.png">
<img class="song" id="0003" src="images/play-button.png">
<img class="song" id="0004" src="images/play-button.png">
<img class="song" id="0005" src="images/play-button.png">
```

I want to open a new stream for each track (each img id is the track id) from soundcloud... so far all i can do is have one song play and pause when any of the buttons is pressed with the following code:

```
var i = $('.song').attr('id');
var is_playing = false;
var player;

SC.stream('/tracks/'+i).then(function(stream){
        player = stream;
    });

$('.song').click(function(){
    if(is_playing == false){
        player.play();
        is_playing = true;
    } else {
        player.pause();
        is_playing = false;
    }
});
```

is it also possible to stop a previous stream when a new stream starts? thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safe the #id in currentPlaying (for example) and now you can check if you have to open a new stream or play the old one

```
$('.song').each(function() {
  var i = $(this).attr('id');
  $(this).click(function(){
    if(is_playing == false){
        if(currentPlaying != i) {
                if(player) player.pause();
                SC.stream('/tracks/'+i).then(function(stream){
                    player = stream;
                });
        }
        player.play();
        is_playing = true;
    } else {
        player.pause();
        is_playing = false;
    }
  });
});
```